# How do I clear framebuffer uint color attachement in OpenGL 3.3?

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics

I am using OpenGL 3.3
So I have a framebuffer, which has color, uint and depth-stencil attachements and I have no clue how to clear uint buffer.

I know that in OpenGL 4.6 you can use `glClearTexImage(bufferID, 0, GL_RED_INTEGER, GL_UNSIGNED_IN, &value);`
But 3.3 doesn't have that function and I have to use this function `glClearBufferuiv(GLenum buffer, GLint drawbuffer, const GLuint* value)`, but it just doesn't work

```
GLuint value = 50;
glClearBufferuiv(GL_COLOR, 1, &value);
```

and when I read pixel value of the texture, I get flat `1058140272`(not 50)
I assume this should possible, but there is no answer online.

Replying to comments:
To read the pixel I use mouse coordinates and read pixel underneeth it, mouse coord def correct

```cpp
//attachmentIndex = 1, because this is index of that color attachement
uint32_t Framebuffer::ReadPixel(uint32_t attachmentIndex, int x, int y)
{
    glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 + attachmentIndex);
    uint32_t pixelData;
    glReadPixels(x, y, 1, 1, GL_R32UI, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, &pixelData);
    return pixelData;
}
```

I am using Glad for GL bindings.
The FBO setup is def not the issue, it works, attaching color textures also works
Here's how I create the color texture itself:

```cpp
glTexImage2D(TextureTarget(multisampled), 0, GL_R32UI, width, height, 0, GL_RED_INTEGER, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, nullptr);
```

Also good to know that GL still needs 4 values for clearing color buffer, I'll try to toy with this.

Comment: Can you add the setup of the FBO and the value of attachmentIndex?

Comment: "*when I read pixel value of the texture*" How do you do that? Also, the fact that you're still on GL 3.3 suggests that you're using a very old GL implementation, which may have bugs. Also, when clearing a color buffer, you must *always* provide all four components, even if the target buffer doesn't have them.

Comment: answered both comments in the edit

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> GL_R32UI, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, &pixelData
> ```

That should have given you a `GL_INVALID_ENUM` error. [Pixel transfer formats](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Pixel_Transfer#Pixel_format) don't use image formats like `R32UI`. You need to use `GL_RED_INTEGER` instead.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, however, sadly, this still didn't help, `558887024` is now the pixel data. Looked through the code, seems like I've not made similar mistake anywhere else.
My best guess is that I just need to move to OpenGL 4.4+, which I don't really want to, but if this won't be resolved in near future, I'll switch.